# Change IE9 to IE8 with Selenium WebDriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, ie-developer-tools

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby and am attempting to create a script that will test in IE8. I am unable to find an answer on how to set iedriver to launch in IE8 mode or how to switch it to IE8 after webdriver has launched. I am on Windows 7 so I only have IE9 available to me. The code I am currently using to launch webdriver in IE9 is

```
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked high and low but cannot find any sort of answer to this question. If you need additional info from me I will happily provide it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be easier to just downgrade to IE8, rather than trying to change it with WebDriver.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9

Comment: Thanks I will investigate this to see if it will work for me. I still need to do testing on IE9 so if it would require removing that to go down to 8 then this is an unsatisfactory resolution. I would also have to figure out how to tell it which version of IE to launch if I can have both installed concurrently.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 is not compatible with Windows 7. I need to find a way to use webdriver with IE9 in IE8 mode.

Comment: I'm not sure where you came across that notion, I use IE8 and IE9 on Windows 7 all the time.

Comment: Would you mind providing a specific link to download IE8 for Windows 7? The link you gave talked about uninstalling IE9 which isn't an option for me and the IE8 download link I found http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-8 does not offer a Windows 7 version and the vista version would not install.

Comment: I was under the impression that uninstalling 9 would install 8.  To downgrade, what I've been doing is uninstalling the windows update "Microsoft Internet Explorer 9."

Comment: Uninstalling 9 would mean that I can no longer access 9, correct? I need both 8 and 9.

Comment: @MatthewHelfgott Windows 7 shipped with IE8. There is no separate installer for it. The advice to use VMs is the correct advice. Even if you could programmatically set IE9 into one of its "compatibility modes" for IE8 (which you can't), you would still not be testing on a "true" IE8 installation, and your environment would not be valid, as there are differences between the IE8 emulation and the real thing. You cannot do what you want with a single installation of Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to tell the IE version during run time, you can use `DesiredCapabilities.`

```
  DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = null;
  ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  ieCapabilities.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
  ieCapabilities.setVersion("Version Number");
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

For more info about  `DesiredCapabilities` use this link http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities.

In the comments you said that i need both IE 8 and 9. Actually it is not possible, Windows currently supports to install only one IE version in a box. The IEDriver used the installed version of IE to launch.

If you want to  use multiple version of IE to test then the better option to go with `Windows Virtual Machines`. You can talk with virtual machines by using the `RemoteWebdriver` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is currently not supported by Selenium WebDriver. There is currently an enhancement request for the IE modes to be implemented as a part of the DesiredCapabilities functionality referenced in the comment from Manigandan.

You can follow this enhancement request here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2564

Other possible solutions mentioned on the enhancement request is manipulating the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry key (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx ) or using keyboard commands to open Developer Tools and selecting the mode from there (I am not sure how well this solution would work, as the workaround in Python requires the WebDriver object to be cast as a Selenium 1.0 object).

Comment: I should point out that I **strongly** object to this enhancement request. I believe it to be flawed, and that it's implementation has no place in the IE driver proper. The guiding principle is this: the IE driver should not attempt to change the registry because it would effect all future instantiations of IE on the machine. Even caching the existing value and restoring it is fraught with peril if the IE driver is to have any hope of driving multiple IE instances. The chances of this enhancement request seeing the light of day are slim.